# What is the format for sending curve parameters and the public key using ECDHE key exchange?

Tags: aes, mbedtls, ecdhe

I attempting to use ECDHE key exchange with AES encryption using mbedtls library on client side.The keys are successfully being generated using the 
 [following program](https://github.com/aishwarya1711/mbedtls/blob/development/encrypt_32.c) .
Is there any standard format to attach the curve parameters and public key to the encrypted file so that the server(may use library other than mbedtls) can parse those?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#page-12) defines the supported elliptic curves extensions. This extension is sent as part of the Client Hello message.
The server will send the used curve in its `ServerKeyExchange` message.
The public keys are sent using the `ServerKeyExchange` and `ClientKeyExchange` messages.